# npmで取得したJavaScriptライブラリ (rollup.js) をHTMLから呼び出す方法

Tags: jquery, vue.js, npm, yarn, rollupjs

## 知りたいこと

npmというものを使えばJavaScriptライブラリのバージョン管理ができると聞き少しずつ触って見ておりますが、どのようにしてhtmlからそのJavaScriptを呼び出せばいいのかがわからないので知りたいです。

npmはPHPでいうcomposer、Pythonで言うpip、nimでいうnimbleのようなものだと思っております。
ここも間違っていたらご指摘いただけると嬉しいです。

## 環境

- Windows 10
- yarn 1.10.0

## やったこと

ひとまずrollup.jsでjQueryを使えるようにしてみようと、以下の準備をしています。

jQueryの追加

```
yarn add jquery
```

---

以下も使うらしいのでとりあえず入れてみる

```
yarn add rollup rollup-plugin-node-resolve rollup-plugin-commonjs rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2015-rollup @babel/core
```

これらは以下と認識しております。
こちらも間違っていたらご指摘いただけると幸いです。

- rollup-plugin-node-resolve

  - node_modules配下のJSファイルを読み込むプラグイン？
- rollup-plugin-commonjs

  - CommonJSという、サーバサイドで動くJSの規格に変換するプラグイン？
- rollup-plugin-babel

  - サーバサイドで動くJSの規格をブラウザが認識できる従来のJSに変換するプラグイン？
- babel-preset-es2015-rollup

  - rollup-plugin-babelを動かすプラグイン…？これはわからない…
- @babel/core

  - babelの本体…？

参考にしたページ：
[(1) コンフィグファイル編 | Rollupがちょうどいい感じ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/cognitom/items/e3ac0da00241f427dad6#1-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E7%B7%A8)

---

フォルダ構成

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

rollup.config.jsを作成します。

```js
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';


export default {
    // コンパイル対象JSファイル
    input: [
        './resources/js/jquery.js'
    ],

    // コンパイル済みJSファイルの書き出し先
    output: {
        format: 'cjs',
        dir: './public/js/',
    },

    // コンパイルに利用するオプションと外部プラグイン
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true}),
        commonjs(),
        babel(),
    ]
}
```

`resources/js/jquery.js` ファイルを `public/js/jquery.js` に書き出そうとしております。

---

`resources/js/jquery.js`ファイルは以下のように定義しました。

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
```

---

その後、rollupでコンパイルを行いました。

```
> yarn rollup -c
```

すると無事、`public/js/jquery.js`が出力されました。

---

HTMLを作成し、先程出力された`public/js/jquery.js`を読み込んで実行してみます。

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- 先程rollupjsが出力したJSファイル -->
        <script src="public/js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="hoge"></div>

        <!-- jQueryを使ってみる -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#hoge').text('hello');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

しかし、上記HTMLファイルにブラウザでアクセスしてみると、

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

のようなエラーが出ております。

これはなぜなのでしょうか？

rollup.config.js中で、

```
nodeResolve({jsnext: true}), // node_modulesからjqueryを取得
↓
commonjs(),                  // サーバ上で動作するJavaScriptに変換（CommonJSの規約に則った変換）
↓
babel(),                     // ブラウザが認識できるJavaScriptに変換
```

と行っていると思いますが、実行できない意味がわかりません。

エラー分的には`$ is not defined`、つまりjQueryの`$`がないという意味ですが、
コンパイル前の`resources/js/jquery.js`で`import $ from 'jquery'`と読み込んでおります。

この後vue.jsやmaterializeを利用しようと考えておりますが、初手でつまずいてしまい……
このあたり、エラーの理由と解決策、私の認識間違いのご指摘をいただけますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rollupなど、モジュールバンドラでimportした外部リソースは基本的に、明示的に外部から利用できるようにする（たとえば`window.$=$`）などしないとその外からは扱えません。（そもそもビルド時に使用していないimportは無視される気がします。）

さらに言えば、そもそもimportだけをするのではなくアプリのJSコードはバンドルするコード内に書くのが一般的ですし、そうすれば前述のように明示的に外に出す必要もありません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。大変申し訳無いのですが、前提部分にも記載させていただきましたが、フロントエンドはあまりわかっておらず…

例えば、「明示的に外部から利用できるようにする（たとえばwindow.$=$）などしないとその外からは扱えません」とのことですが、
vuejsなどではどうするのでしょうか？
「window.vue=vue」などになるのでしょうか？

Comment: 今試しに、「window.$=$」を追記し、コンパイルし直してみるとたしかに実行することができました。
HTMLから実行できるようなJSに変換するにはすべてのライブラリ（例：vuejs, sweet alert, riot, handlebarsなど）をwindows.XXに書いていく必要があるということでしょうか？

Comment: もしHTML内にコードを書く、現状のようなコードを書く、とするならばそうすることになりますが、それであればRollupを使ってる意味がないですし、なんならunpkg等から読み込んだほうが楽まであります。HTML内にJSコードを書く特別な理由がないのであれば、バンドル内にまとめてしまうべきです。（babelを使ったり、モジュールシステムを活用するにも、あるいはVueのSFCを使うにもそうすべきです。）

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます！なるほどなるほど、少しずつ分かってきました！ありがとうございます！